# Windows: Get system auto lock remaining time

Tags: windows, winapi, system, undocumented-behavior

How to get the remaining time to the next system auto locking or auto sleep?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the time to next sleep by using [`CallNtPowerInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-callntpowerinformation) with the `SystemPowerInformation` option and then look at the `TimeRemaining` field in the returned struct. However, this can be always `0`. So, let's see another approach.

- [`GetLastInputInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo) will give you the time (in ticks) when the last user input (such as keypress or mouse move) happened.
- [`SystemParametersInfoW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow) function with the `SPI_GETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT` flag will get the screensaver timeout from Windows settings (in seconds).

Combine these two with the current time and a "tick to seconds" conversion to find out how long until the screensaver fires.

Also, note that not all users have screensavers or sleep/hybernate enabled. You might have to check these too.

Comment: Yes, I can get the sleep by `CallNtPowerInformation`. But I can't calculate the remainning time to screen saver or auto locking just by last input time.

Comment: Bisides, `GetLastInputInfo` retrieve the last input time, but if any program reset display idle counter by `SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED)`, I would get wrong prediction.

Comment: @user2431141 I have edited answer to show how you can determine time until screen saver. If any program *does* use `SetThreadExecutionState` as you described, it won't screensave anyway.

Comment: If a program call `SetThreadExecutionState`, but it exits for some reason. I think the screen saver will happen.